# Automatic casting of template object to template pointer in c++

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, casting

I have a `URes` class which contains a single pointer to `<T>`, with indirection operators `->` and `*` overloaded so I can use the instance as a pointer directly.

However I also want to be able to pass my `URes` instance to functions that normally take the pointer inside the `URes` instance.

How do I make it so that when my `URes` instance object is passed to a function it is automatically cast to the pointer it contains?

Comment: Please learn to format your posts; three months is plenty of time in which to learn how!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same way that you create *any* outbound conversion: by declaring and defining an operator.

In this case, you want a member `operator T*`.

[Example](http://ideone.com/8Pqjx):

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
   operator T*() {
      return 0;
   }
};

void bar(int* p) {}

int main() {
   Foo<int> f;
   bar(f);
}
```

However, I'd recommend avoiding this and implementing a member `T* get()` instead. It should be an *explicit* step for a calling scope to obtain a pointer from your object.

Comment: I already have the * operator overloaded, does that mean I am good to go? I assumed I had to implement some casts.

Comment: @ddriver: This is not `T& operator*()`, but rather `operator T*()` - note the difference.

Comment: @ddriver: You mean "conversions"; a cast is an explicit conversion, which has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by providing a conversion operator from that class to the pointer-type:

```
class Foo {
public:
    operator int() const { // enables implicit conversion from Foo to int
    }
};
```

Note that such implicit conversion [can introduce unexpected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346083/why-implicit-conversion-is-harmful-in-c).

Comment: It is still a valid example for a user-defined conversion, isn't it?

Comment: Yep, but not the user-defined conversion requested in the question :P